# Design conditional relationship

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I need help with designing my database tables.

**Employee**
Id
EmployeeTypeId

**EmployeeType**
Id
Name

**Car**
Id
EmployeeId

How do I enforce that only one type of employee (driver) can be a foreign key in the Car table or should I redesign the tables?

Comment: I think it depends on your rdbms. In Sql server you can't do it with only a foreign key constraint, you have to add a check constraint to the Car table, to check the EmployeeType. Other databases might have other solutions. (I know, for instance, that MySql doesn't enforce check constraints, so you will have to come up with a different solution).

Comment: To me this sounds like a business rule, and I tend to try to keep business logic out of the database, and in the business layer and/or CRUD operations.

Comment: And I on the other hand like to have business rules in the database. Once the database prevents implausible inserts, you simply cannot make mistakes that lead to inconsistent data. If you mistakenly want to input which car the gardener drives for the company you'll get an exception. It is, however, not so easy to enforce this in the constellation given.

Comment: In MS SQL you may create a view [VCar] WITH CHECK OPTION and insert into this view instead of [Car].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider it a good idea to forearm the database such that implausible data cannot be entered. To enforce this here, however, is a bit tricky...

Solution 1:

Add EmployeeTypeId to the Car table. Then make (EmployeeId, EmployeeTypeId) a foreign key to the Employee table (where you might have to create a uniqe constraint on the two fields, in order to be able to use them for a foreign key reference). Then add a constraint on Car.EmployeeTypeId to ensure it's a driver. I know this looks redundant, but it really is no problem, because you cannot assign an Employee another EmployeeType here, so consistency is still guaranteed. I admit this approach is a bit clumsy, though.

Solution 2:

Use a before-insert tigger on the Car table, look up the employee and make sure it is a driver, else throw an exception. This is a better solution in my opinion, alone for its simplicity. You could then add a column to table Car holding a unique name for the types that you use, e.g. UniqueName = 'DRIVER', so you don't have to use the ID as a magic number. You see, normally one EmployeeType is a s good as the other in a database. If you want to build special logic on a certain entry, you need a handle for this. The unique name is one way to do this, a flag IsDriver = TRUE/FALSE would be another.

Comment: If Car Driver must take part in a number of specific relationships i'd better  create subtype entity.  Concerning triggers option note one also need trigger on Employee update to catch this person is not driver any more but still is  referenced from Cars.

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice to reference a UNIQUE constraint in a FOREIGN KEY ?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. The *parent* table has a column or a group of columns that are unique. The foreign key in the cild table references this column or this group of columns.